# Call ViewSet method from another view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a mobile app with a Django REST framework API and I have a lot of ModelViewSet that I call to retrieve data. I have performance issue because I need to call a lot of routes after the user login, and I would like to keep the REST logic but also returns after the login all the viewsets content in the login response (keeping their filters).

Is it possible to call a ModelViewset list() from another view (viewset or APIView)?

The only answer I found on SO was to do something like this

```
class ContentGenerator(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
         data = MyModelViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})(request).data

         return Response({'data': data})
```

But it is not supported

```
Exception Value: The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`
```

Is there another solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some research, it looks like there might be side-effects to reuse the request in other views, so it is not officially supported by DRF. It is hacky, but if you know what you are doing, this is a solution.

```
data = MyModelViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})(request._request).data
```

Comment: A note of caution: This seems to work fine with `GET` requests, but for `POST`, I get this error: `django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream`.

Comment: What about patch call where we have to pass parameter in url like /some/url/id ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this in 2 ways. Assume I have a `view A` and a `viewset B` and that I want to call `B.my_action` from `A`. `B.my_action` handles a specific id e.g. user id, product id etc.

**1st way**

`code w/in BViewSet`

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
def my_action(self, request, pk=None):
 try:
   # works when you call from web UI, through router
   # automatically you have one specific view corresponding
   # to specific id e.g. user id, product id etc
   instance = self.get_object()
 except AttributeError as ae:
   # here you don't have a specific view instantiated
   # and you have many ids e.g. user ids, product ids etc
   # pick one id
   instance = MyModelObject.objects.get(id=pk)

 # rest of code as is, no change
```

`code w/in e.g. AView.utils.py that calls BViewSet.my_action`

Below `request` is the request passed to `AView` when `AView` called
through web UI.

```
from django.http import HttpRequest

data = BViewSet(detail=True)
new_request = HttpRequest()
new_request.data = any_data_I_need_to_pass # e.g. request.data

ret = data.my_action(new_request, pk=request.data['id'])
return ret
```

**2nd way**

I decoupled `my_action` functionality from `my_action` call i.e.

`code w/in BViewSet`

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
def my_action(self, request, pk=None):
  instance = self.get_object()
  ret = my_action_server(instance, request.data)
  return Response(data=ret)

def my_action_server(instance, data):
   # all code comes here
   return result
```

`code w/in Aview`

```
# import my_action_server as needed
# call my_action_server
# AView should provide everything needed
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, was enought to do this:

```
data = MyClassViewSet()
for i in data.queryset:
   # Then you can access to any field of your model like this:
   i.id
   i.name
   ...
   # And do what you need
```

But obviously this is only for `{'get':'list'}`

If the method is an extra action (i.g: products_filtered_by_user), you could do this:

```
data = MyClassViewSet()
data.products_filtered_by_user(request,user=kwargs['user_id'])
if data.code == 200:
    response_data = data.response_data
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how to call extra actions? For my extra action I have this decorator `@action(detail=True, methods=['post'])` and if I call it from web UI, the url is `http://.../my_id/my_action`. I suppose in your example, I should replace `user` by `id` and `user_id` by `my_id`.

Comment: Sure, first of all, you need to use ```detail=True``` if the action is a list or a detail view. I recommend you to reorder your url, something like ```api/v1/my_action/id/<int:my_id>``` so yes, you need to replace ```user``` by ```id``` and ```ùser``` by ```my_id``` check the drf documentation for more information https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Comment: Not there yet. 1. I call the desired view from `utils.py` of another view, if it makes a difference. Then, I do `MyViewSet(detail=True).my_action(request, pk=request.data['my_id'])` which successfully invokes `my_action` but when I do in the action `instance = self.get_object()` I get the error `AttributeError: 'MyViewSet' object has no attribute 'kwargs'`. `MyViewSet` has both a `queryset = My.objects.all()` and `serializer_class = MySerialzer`. Finally, `@action(detail=True, methods=['post']
def my_action(self, request, pk=None):
     instance = self.get_object()`

Comment: As I understand it, my problem is that I don't have a specific instance when I call `MyViewSet.my_action()`. I have a collection of objects as it seems. Btw `basename` is `None`.

Comment: I think you shouldn't need to pass ```detail=True``` when you call ```MyViewSet```, so you can call it ```MyViewSet().my_action(request,pk=request.data['my_id'])``` (or make an instance of your class). Have you tried defined your action like ```def my_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs)``` and in your ```kwargs``` receive the ```pk``` variable?